# FileNotFound exception but there is a file (Java Eclipse)

Tags: java, exception, filereader, filenotfoundexception

I cant get rid of this FileNotFound error even though the file exists. Any ideas? (There are hundreds of lines of code so im just going to paste the chunk around the error, if this is an issue I can post more)

```
// method start
                System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
                File names = new File("src/guiProject/nameList");
                System.out.println(names.getAbsolutePath());
                //                                !!!! V ERROR OCCURS HERE V !!!!
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(names));
                try {
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    String line = br.readLine();

                    while (line != null) {
                        sb.append(line);
                        line = br.readLine();
                    }
                    String allNames = sb.toString();
                    userListArea.setText(allNames);
                } catch (IOException o) {
                    o.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    try {
                        br.close();
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
//method end
```

Comment: That is a relative path to the file. Are you sure you are running the application with the current directory set to the folder above that "src"?

Comment: Yes, I am running it in the same directory

Comment: "Same directory" meaning? Print the result of `System.getProperty("user.dir")` just before this bit of code. What do you get?

Comment: Most likely, you're not actually reading from where you think you are. You can get the absolute path with `File#getAbsolutePath`.

Comment: @RealSkeptic I tried running that code and it seemed to just skip over it because it went straight to FileNotFound error

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider How would I implement that, im new at this sort of stuff so sorry if its simple.

Comment: Before creating the BufferedReader, add `System.out.println(names.getAbsolutePath());`.

Comment: It's hard to understand whether you did exactly what I told you. Did you wrap the code I wrote in a `System.out.println(...)`? Did you make sure you rebuilt the application and ran it again after that? Code is never just "skipped".

Comment: @VGR FileNotFound Error

Comment: Yes, a println statement would not prevent that error.  But you should see a line of output before that error is printed.  What does that line look like?  Is it the full path of an existing file?

Comment: @RealSkeptic I did wrap it in System.out.println, I did rebuild it and ran it again, it keeps jumping straight to FileNotFound

Comment: @VGR There is nothing before the error

Comment: Just to make sure im not an idiot and wasting everyones time, System.out.println() would print it in the console, correct?

Comment: That is correct.  Are you sure your println statement is before `new BufferedReader`?

Comment: @VGR yes, it is in the line directly above

Comment: A stack trace would be very useful here.  Never, ever write an empty `catch` block under any circumstances.  At the very least, print the stack trace, with something like `o.printStackTrace();`.  Once you’ve added that and run again, edit your question and add the full stack trace to it.

Comment: @VGR Question has been updated to show where I have implemented your suggestion and where ive added Stack Trace, nothing changed with the output.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your Windows does not show file extensions; nameList.txt?
Otherwise the working directory is not in the project directory with subdirectory src.

A `FileReader` uses the default Charset, so the file is not portable. If you run the application on another platform then the developer's, the encoding is wrong.
Best use UTF-8, full Unicode.

Then the reading strips the line ending:

```
                while (line != null) {
                    sb.append(line).append("\r\n");
                    line = br.readLine();
                }
```

You could do:

```
            Path names = Paths.get("src/guiProject/nameList.txt"); // File
            Path names = Paths.get(
                MyClass.class.getResource("/guiProject/nameList.txt").toURI()); // Resource

            String allNames = new String(Files.readAllBytes(names), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            userListArea.setText(allNames);
```

If it is a read-only file, stored in the application jar, it is a *resource* rather than a disk *File*.

Comment: Im getting an error saying I need to add "}" to the end of the line with .toURI() to complete the class body? How do I fix this?

Comment: Forgot a `(` after getResource and befor `"`

Comment: Its also giving me an error for StandardCharsets, do I need to import something?

Comment: Yes, the IDE will help. On Androids there is no StandardCharsets however. Als `"UTF-8"` is possible. The advantage of StandardCharsets which lists every available Charset is that one exception less can occur.

Comment: What specifically do I have to import, as I said earlier in the comments, I am relatively new to this sort of stuff.

Comment: The IDE will normally help. `import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;` But try it first to let the IDE help, as this will be something happening often: using some still not imported class.

Comment: Could you please explain why there are 2 variables with the same name?

Comment: I am also getting an exception not handled error, its an URISyntaxException on the line with .toURI()

Comment: Where you catch the IOException you could `catch` that exception too.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are not in the folder you think.

Create a file with a dummy name and get the absolute path of this file, this way you can doublecheck you are where you think you really are.